# Can Eclipse (Oxygen) automatically find all Header files in a project?

Tags: eclipse, stm32, include-path

I have imported a very large project for an STM32F4 that I have found online. I was going through including all the .h files in folders when I realised the program structure had them everywhere and outside of neat Inc/Include folder.

The method I normally use is go to Project Properties>C/C++ Build>Settings>Tool Setting Tab> then include the folders in the Includes boxes provided, the "-I" box.

This is very tedious; is there a better way?

Comment: No. Otherwise you would include not needed ones as well